# Python, Save image from Open CV with cv::imwrite - error message permission denied [WARN:0]

Tags: python, image, opencv

This is the code.

First part is for Telegram. Second part logging and directory folder creation. Third part detection of an image with CAFFE. After that we mark the picture with different zones.
Then we export the data to MySQL.
After it, row 208 we have the imwrite (you can also see that I have tried in my personal directory, but I have a special character there (C:/Users/César/) and I am not sure if this is the key for that.

```
import numpy as np
import argparse
import cv2
import time
import mysql.connector
import json
from datetime import datetime
from influxdb import InfluxDBClient
import ast
import os
import logging
from telegram.ext import Updater, CommandHandler, MessageHandler, Filters
import threading 

# ---------------------
# TELEGRAM Handlers
def people_total(update, context):
    update.message.reply_text('Total number of people present in store:' + str(total))

def zone_risk(update, context):
    update.message.reply_text('Risky zones due to people presence'+ label2)

def echo(update, context):
    """Echo the user message."""
    update.message.reply_text('Total number of people is:'+ label)
    # update.message.reply_text(update.message.text)

def pic(update, context):
    chat_id = update.message.chat_id        # get the recipient´s ID
    #context.bot.sendPhoto(chat_id=chat_id, photo=open(path, 'rb'))
    context.bot.sendPhoto(chat_id=chat_id, photo=open('./hall.jpg', 'rb'))

def main_telegram():
    """Start the bot."""
    # Create the Updater and pass it your bot's token.
    # Make sure to set use_context=True to use the new context based callbacks
    # Post version 12 this will no longer be necessary
    updater = Updater("xxxxx", use_context=True)

    # Get the dispatcher to register handlers
    dp = updater.dispatcher

    # on different commands - answer in Telegram
    dp.add_handler(CommandHandler("people", people_total))
    dp.add_handler(CommandHandler("risk", zone_risk))
    dp.add_handler(CommandHandler("picture", pic))

    # on noncommand i.e message - echo the message on Telegram
    dp.add_handler(MessageHandler(Filters.text & ~Filters.command, echo))

   
    # Start the Bot
    updater.start_polling()

    # Run the bot until you press Ctrl-C or the process receives SIGINT,
    # SIGTERM or SIGABRT. This should be used most of the time, since
    # start_polling() is non-blocking and will stop the bot gracefully.
#    updater.idle()
# ---------------------
# TELEGRAM Enable logging
logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s',
                    level=logging.INFO)

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
# ---------------------
# THREADING
# threading.Thread(target=main_telegram).start() 
telegram_thread = threading.Thread(target=main_telegram, args=())
telegram_thread.start() # starts main telegram program in a separate thread
# ---------------------
# import pandas as pd

# INFLUXDB
# client = InfluxDBClient('xxxx', xx, 'xx', 'xxx', 'xxxx')
# client.create_database('TRIALDB') # Problems with DB creation
# ---------------------
# SUB-DIRECTORY CREATION
working_path = os.getcwd()
# sub_directory = "Image"
# path = os.path.join(working_path, sub_directory) 
path = working_path
os.makedirs(path, exist_ok = True)
print(path)
# ---------------------
# CAFFE construct the argument parse and parse the arguments
ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-i", "--image", required=True,
     help="path to input image")
ap.add_argument("-p", "--prototxt", required=True,
     help="path to Caffe 'deploy' prototxt file")
ap.add_argument("-m", "--model", required=True,
     help="path to Caffe pre-trained model")
ap.add_argument("-c", "--confidence", type=float, default=0.2,
     help="minimum probability to filter weak detections")
args = vars(ap.parse_args())
CLASSES = ["background", "aeroplane", "bicycle", "bird", "boat",
     "bottle", "bus", "car", "cat", "chair", "cow", "diningtable",
     "dog", "horse", "motorbike", "person", "pottedplant", "sheep",
     "sofa", "train", "tvmonitor"]
COLORS = np.random.uniform(0, 255, size=(len(CLASSES), 3))
print("[INFO] loading model…")
image = cv2.imread(args["image"])
net = cv2.dnn.readNetFromCaffe(args["prototxt"], args["model"])
(h, w) = image.shape[:2]
blob = cv2.dnn.blobFromImage(cv2.resize(image, (300, 300)), 0.007843, (300, 300), 127.5)
print("[INFO] computing object detections…")
print(blob.shape)
net.setInput(blob)
detections = net.forward()
# ---------------------
# RECTANGLE LISTS DEFINITION BASED ON APPLE.JPG + ZONE COUNTER CREATION
StartXlist = [1,230,580,30,275,460,155,295,415,200,300,390]
StartYlist = [265,265,265,120,120,120,68,68,68,40,40,40]
EndXlist = [90,430,640,210,380,620,240,355,510,255,355,465]
EndYlist = [420,420,420,220,220,220,110,110,110,65,65,65]
PeopleinZone=[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
LimitpeopleZone= [3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3]
Risk = ["NO","NO","NO","NO","NO","NO","NO","NO","NO","NO","NO","NO"]
# ---------------------
for r in range(0,12):
      cv2.rectangle(image, (StartXlist[r], StartYlist[r]), (EndXlist[r], EndYlist[r]),         (0,255,255), 2) # Black color in BGR
      y = StartYlist[r] - 15 if StartYlist[r] - 15 > 15 else StartYlist[r] + 15     
      cv2.putText(image,'Zone'+str(r+1), (StartXlist[r], y),cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, (0,255,255), 2)

for i in np.arange(0, detections.shape[2]):
     confidence = detections[0, 0, i, 2]
         
     if confidence > args["confidence"]:
            idx = int(detections[0, 0, i, 1])
            box = detections[0, 0, i, 3:7] * np.array([w, h, w, h])
            (startX, startY, endX, endY) = box.astype("int")      
            # label = '{}"class": {}, "confidence": {:.4f}, "startX": {}, "startY": {}, "EndX": {},  "EndY": {},  "Timestamp": {}{}'.format(chr(123),chr(34)+CLASSES[idx]+chr(34), confidence,startX,startY,endX,endY,chr(34)+str(datetime.now())+chr(34),chr(125)) 
            # label = json.dumps({'class': CLASSES[idx],"confidence": str(round(confidence * 100, 1)) + "%","startX": str(startX),"startY": str(startY),"EndX": str(endX),"EndY": str(endY),"Timestamp": datetime.now().strftime("%d/%m/%Y, %H:%M")})
            # print("[INFO] {}".format(label))
            # print(label3)
            # var person = { "name": "John", "age": 31, "city": "New York" }; JSON FORMAT FOUND
            
            ## Create table
            # val1 = json.loads(label3)
            # print(*val1)
          
            # df = pd.DataFrame(val1, index=list(range(1)))
            # print(df)
            ##
            if CLASSES[idx] == "person":
               for j in range(0,12):
                     dx= min(EndXlist[j],endX)-max(StartXlist[j],startX)
                     dy= min(EndYlist[j],endY)-max(StartYlist[j],startY)
                     if (dx>=0) and (dy>=0):
                          PeopleinZone[j]+= 1
                     # print("Zone"+str(j+1)+" dx: "+str(dx)+"dy: "+str(dy))
                     # print(PeopleinZone)
                     
print(PeopleinZone)            
# ---------------------
# MYSQL
mydb = mysql.connector.connect( host="xx", user="xx", password="xx")
# Check if connection was successful
if (mydb):
     # Carry out normal procedure
     print ("Connection successful")
else:
     # Terminate
     print ("Connection unsuccessful")
mycursor = mydb.cursor()
dbname="TFM40"
mySql_Create_db = "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS "+dbname
mycursor.execute(mySql_Create_db)
mysql_use_db = "USE "+dbname
mycursor.execute(mysql_use_db)
x = datetime.now()
tablename="T"+str(x.year)+str(x.month)+str(x.day)
# mySql_Create_Table = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "+tablename +"(id int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, Classification varchar(250), Confidence varchar(250), StartX varchar(250), StartY varchar(250), EndX varchar(250), EndY varchar(250), Timestamp varchar(250))"
mySql_Create_Table2 = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "+tablename +"(id int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, Camera varchar(250), Zone1 float,  Zone2 float, Zone3 float, Zone4 float, Zone5 float, Zone6 float, Zone7 float, Zone8 float, Zone9 float, Zone10 float, Zone11 float, Zone12 float, Timestamp timestamp)"
print(mySql_Create_Table2)
mycursor.execute (mySql_Create_Table2)
# sql_insert = "INSERT INTO "+dbname+"."+tablename+" (Classification,Confidence,startX,startY,EndX,EndY,Timestamp) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)"
sql_insert2 = "INSERT INTO "+dbname+"."+tablename+" (Camera, Zone1, Zone2, Zone3, Zone4, Zone5, Zone6, Zone7, Zone8, Zone9, Zone10, Zone11, Zone12, Timestamp) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)"
# val = (str(CLASSES[idx]),str(round(confidence * 100, 1)),str(startX),str(startY),str(endX),str(endY),str(x))
val2 = ('hall',PeopleinZone[0],PeopleinZone[1],PeopleinZone[2],PeopleinZone[3],PeopleinZone[4],PeopleinZone[5],PeopleinZone[6],PeopleinZone[7],PeopleinZone[8],PeopleinZone[9],PeopleinZone[10],PeopleinZone[11],str(x))
# mycursor.execute(sql_insert,(val))
mycursor.execute(sql_insert2,(val2))
# mycursor.execute(sql_insert,(val,)) WORKS BUT IT IS FOR TUPLES
mydb.commit()
           
           
            
           # python main.py --prototxt MobileNetSSD_deploy.prototxt --model MobileNetSSD_deploy.caffemodel --image EXECUTION
            
           # cursor.close()



            # mydb.close()
            
            # INFLUXDB

            # client = InfluxDBClient(host, port, user, password, dbname)
            # client = InfluxDBClient('vps656540.ovh.net', 3306, 'master26', 'master26_', 'TRIALDB')
            # client.create_database('TRIALDB') 
            #DRAW SQUARE 
            #cv2.rectangle(image, (startX, startY), (endX, endY),         COLORS[idx], 2)  DEFINE OBJECTS DETECTED SQUARE   
            
            #y = startY - 15 if startY - 15 > 15 else startY + 15  VERTICAL POSITION OF CLASS TITLE    
            #cv2.putText(image, label, (startX, y),cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, COLORS[idx], 2) TITLE INSERTION INTO IMAGE
cv2.imshow("Output", image)
#cv2.imwrite('C:/Users/César/Pictures/hall.jpg', image)
cv2.imwrite(os.path.join(path, '/hall.jpg'), image)
print(os.path.join(path, 'hall.jpg'))
cv2.waitKey(10000) # video (cambiamos un 0 por un 1)
# --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# TELEGRAM
# label = '{}"Camera": {}, "Zone1": {}, "Zone2": {}, "Zone3": {}, "Zone4": {}, "Zone5": {}, "Zone6": {}, "Zone7": {}, "Zone8": {}, "Zone9": {}, "Zone10": {},"Zone11": {},"Zone12": {}, "Timestamp": {}{}'.format(chr(123),chr(34)+'hall'+chr(34), PeopleinZone[0],PeopleinZone[1],PeopleinZone[2],PeopleinZone[3],PeopleinZone[4],PeopleinZone[5],PeopleinZone[6],PeopleinZone[7],PeopleinZone[8],PeopleinZone[9],PeopleinZone[10],PeopleinZone[11],chr(34)+str(datetime.now())+chr(34),chr(125)) 
# QUESTION & ANSWER 1
total=0
maximum=0
for z in range(0,12):
     total += PeopleinZone[z]
     maximum += LimitpeopleZone[z]
     if PeopleinZone[z]>= LimitpeopleZone[z]:
          Risk[z] ='YES'
     else:
          Risk[z] ='NO'
label = json.dumps({"Total people" : total, "Remaining people to reach limit" : (maximum - total),"Timestamp": datetime.now().strftime("%d/%m/%Y, %H:%M")})
print(label)
# ---------------------
# QUESTION & ANSWER 2
# label2 = json.dumps({"Camera": "hall", "Zone1": PeopleinZone[0],"Zone2": PeopleinZone[1],"Zone3": PeopleinZone[2],"Zone4": PeopleinZone[3],"Zone5": PeopleinZone[4],"Zone6": PeopleinZone[5],"Zone7": PeopleinZone[6],"Zone8": PeopleinZone[7],"Zone9": PeopleinZone[8],"Zone10": PeopleinZone[9],"Zone11": PeopleinZone[10],"Zone12": PeopleinZone[11],"Timestamp": datetime.now().strftime("%d/%m/%Y, %H:%M")})
label2 = json.dumps({"Camera": "hall", "Zone1 Risk": Risk[0],"Zone2 Risk": Risk[1],"Zone3 Risk": Risk[2],"Zone4 Risk": Risk[3],"Zone5 Risk": Risk[4],"Zone6 Risk": Risk[5],"Zone7 Risk": Risk[6],"Zone8 Risk": Risk[7],"Zone9 Risk": Risk[8],"Zone10 Risk": Risk[9],"Zone11 Risk": Risk[10],"Zone12 Risk": Risk[11],"Timestamp": datetime.now().strftime("%d/%m/%Y, %H:%M")})
print(label2)

telegram_thread.join()
# ---------------------s
#
```

when I try to save an image with imwrite from OpenCV, I receive the following error message:

```
[ WARN:0] global C:\Users\appveyor\AppData\Local\Temp\1\pip-req-build-k8sx3e60\opencv\modules\imgcodecs\src\loadsave.cpp (710) cv::imwrite_ imwrite_('C:\hall.jpg'): can't open file for writing: permission denied
```

Did this happen to someone else?

Thanks,

Comment: Try writing to your Home folder, e.g: `C:\Users\Cesar\hall.png`

Comment: I have already tried. It is strange because it does not give an error, but it does not save the picture.

Comment: Share the code snipppet please